# Before and AfterBuild Target in Visual Studio not firing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am doing the following:

- I have created a default class file project
- Edited the csproj file to include Pre and Post BuildEvents
- Uncomment the default commented out BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets

The BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets are not called form within Visual Studio but are from msbuild command line, why is that?

I would rather use msbuild targets rather than the PostBuildEvent as if gives me more power and flexibility, assuming it works.

Cheers,

adam

*I shortened some of the paths in the output, so if they are inconsistent that is why*

---

ClassLibrary1.csproj changes

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="### BeforeBuild ###" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="### AfterBuild ###" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>echo PRE_BUILD</PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
 <PostBuildEvent>echo POST_BUILD</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

my build output from VS 2010 is

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: ClassLibrary1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
PRE_BUILD
ClassLibrary1 -> c:\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll
POST_BUILD
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

and from the command line

```
#>msbuild ClassLibrary1.sln
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.239]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 09/05/2012 13:27:42.
Project "c:.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "c:.sln" (1) is building "c:\ClassLibrary1.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
    BeforeBuild:
      ### BeforeBuild ###
PreBuildEvent:
  echo PRE_BUILD
  PRE_BUILD
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  ClassLibrary1 -> c:\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll
PostBuildEvent:
  echo POST_BUILD
  POST_BUILD
AfterBuild:
  ### AfterBuild ###
Done Building Project "c:\ClassLibrary1.csproj" (default targets).

Done Building Project "c:.sln" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.18
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your build events are firing, you're just not seeing them in Visual Studio.

By default VS sets the msbuild verbosity to `minimal`.  You can get your message to show by changing the message importance to `high`

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="### BeforeBuild ###"  Importance="high" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="### AfterBuild ###" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

You can also change the verbosity setting in VS under Tools->Options then under Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.

Comment: thanks, I was only at the stage of testing that things worked before moving onto the actual work I was expecting to do. I'll look at changing the default verbosity

Comment: It is probably also worth noting that property definitions used therein should be defined in an unnamed ItemGroup near the top of the project defintion.

Answer (score 12):

Just for others help, when they encounter similar issue but the reason could be different. 
If you have import after the target then also AfterBuild may not work.

**Make sure all the import you have should be before Target Definition, Target Definition should be at the end**