# ReferencePath vs. ReferenceCopyLocalPaths

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is there any difference between `ReferencePath` with condition `'%(CopyLocal)'=='true'` and `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths`?

The question was raised by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337377/188826) answer which uses both ways in two pieces of code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ReferencePath`: Paths to resolved primary files.

`ReferenceCopyLocalPaths`: references that are marked as `"CopyLocal"` and their dependencies, including .pdbs, .xmls and satellites.

To test each item contents, add this to your .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="1. ReferencePath:%0D%0A%09@(ReferencePath->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)', '%0D%0A%09')" />
    <Message Text="2. ReferenceCopyLocalPaths:%0D%0A%09@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)', '%0D%0A%09')" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Don't forget about ```Importance="High"``` attribute if you build project by Visual Studio. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518668/1193727