# How to build a web app MVC5-WEB API 2 in Azure Devops with CLI?

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, command-line-interface, publish

I want to build a web app (web api 2) in Azure but i don't want to obtain a zip, i just want to get a directory with all necessary files. I don't know the command line to do that.
I don't want to use the classical deploy web app task because i need to add additional files after the build. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Leo, thank you so much for your answer. I was stucked but you helped me a lot with : /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish

Comment: Everything is perfect. I've just missed to validate your answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to build a web app MVC5-WEB API 2 in Azure Devops with CLI?

You could use **Visual Studio Build task** with MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
```

to publish web app to artifact folder or any other folder you want.

You also can specify the publish profile directly:

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="{publish profile name}";publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
```

With **FileSystem publish** method, the published files are in a folder, not zipped.

And if you want use the command line task instead of Visual Studio Build task, you could invoke MSBuild.exe with same MSBuild Arguments to build this solution/project:

```
"<PathForMSBuild.exeOnYourAgent>\MSBuild.exe" "<YourProject/SolutionPath>" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
```

[image]

If you want to add additional files after the build, you could add a task after Visual Studio build task, or you can create [`AfterBuild`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516336/before-and-afterbuild-target-in-visual-studio-not-firing) Target in your project to add additional files.

Hope this helps.